# How to include "refetchQueries" option into React Apollo Query with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using typescript in a React project using Apollo client, I have a simple update customer form that requires a mutation inside of a Query for getting the Customer data to show from his/her ID, I have created (as per Apollo Typescript documentation) a specialized query object for this,

```js
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Imports Section (React/Apollo Libs)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import { gql }                  from 'apollo-boost';
import { Query }                from 'react-apollo'

import { getCustomerById }            from '../../typeDefs/operations/getCustomerById'
import { getCustomerByIdVariables }   from '../../typeDefs/operations/getCustomerById'

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GQL Query: Customers
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export const Q_GET_CUSTOMER_BY_ID = gql`
    query getCustomerById($id: ID) {
        getCustomer(id: $id)
        {
            first_name
            last_name
            company
            emails {
                email
            }
            age
            type
        }
    }
`;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Query Class: Customers
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export class QueryGetCustomerById extends Query<getCustomerById, getCustomerByIdVariables> { }
```

Everything works as expected... until entering the "Edit Customer" view again after the change, where the data seems unchanged, (this obviously because of Apollo Cache), when trying to use the "refetchQuery" option in the `<QueryGetCustomerById>` Typescript sends a weird error to my VSCode window.

[image: Type errors caused by the 'refetchQueries' property]

Reading the Apollo Typescript documentation (very lacking IMHO) I find that there is a reference in its second example to a ChildProps object, now I am not sure if I should declare or create another interface for the `QueryGetCustomerById` to take together with the Response and Variables ones. Quite honestly I am totally confused at this point, if someone has tried this or knows how to implement it please help. Thanks a lot.

P.S. Using the more generic version `<Query<getCustomerById, getCustomerByIdVariables> ...` doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My bad...

Doing a more careful revision in the Apollo Docs site, I found the `<Query>` tag can pass a 'refetch()' method to the query in the returning arrow function, which in turn can be executed after the mutation function. I just tried it and it worked great!  Here is the code for if someone ever falls into the same issue and sees this page..

```js
               <QueryGetCustomerById 
                    query={Q_GET_CUSTOMER_BY_ID} 
                    variables={{ id: id }}
                >
                    {({ loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
                        if (loading)
                        {
                            return "Put something that looks good for loading here..."
                        }
                        if (error)
                        {
                            return `Error: ${error.message}` 
                        }
                        if (data && data.getCustomer)
                        {
                            this.setCustomer(id, data.getCustomer as CustomerInput)
                        }
                        return (
                            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                                <MutationUpdateCustomer 
                                    mutation={M_UPDATE_CUSTOMER}
                                    onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')}
                                >
                                {
                                    (updateCustomer) => {
                                        return (
                                            <form name="frmEditCustomer"
                                                className="col-md-8 m-3"
                                                onSubmit={e => this.frmEditCustomer_submit(e, updateCustomer, refetch)}
                                                onChange={e => this.frmEditCustomer_change(e)}
                                            >
...
```

refetch() is sent as another parameter in the form_submit() eventhandler, so it can be later executed...

```js
            try
            {
                await updateCustomer({
                    variables: { input }
                })

                await refetch()

                Swal.fire(
                    'Update Customer',
                    'Customer data has been successfully saved.',
                    'success'
                )
            }
            catch (error)
            {
...
```

The lesson today for me has been not to believe any blog post I find in the web without checking the official documentation. I hope this post may be useful to someone.